# Customize laravel elixir livereload

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir, gulp-livereload

I need to perform after mix.less ('app.less') automatically reloads the page. What would not press each time F5
gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Less
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */



elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap-switch/dist', 'public/packages/bootstrap-switch');
});
```

Is it possible to use it as a gulp browser-sync ?

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid there is no way to use livereload with elixir yet.
I suggest you to quite using elixir and start using all the freedom of general versatile gulp plugins.

My recipe for live reload with Livereload:

1. Install Livereload plugin for Chrome
2. Enable it pressing its button in Chrome’s toolbar
3. Install gulp-modules:

   npm install gulp gulp-plumber gulp-connect gulp-sass --save-dev
4. Create simple gulpfile (with livereload of *.scss files only) like
   below.
5. run gulp

Example of gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('public/css/*.sass')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass'], function () {
    gulp.watch(['resources/assets/sass/*.scss'],
        function (e) {
            gulp.src(e.path)
                .pipe(plumber())
                .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
            ;
        }
    );
    gulp.watch(['public/css/*.css',],
        function (e) {
            gulp.src(e.path)
                .pipe(connect.reload())
            ;
        }
    );
});

gulp.task('server', ['watch'], function () {
    connect.server({
        root: 'public',
        livereload: true
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['server']);
```

Answer (score 0):

First install a plugin called laravel-elixir-livereload with

`npm install --save-dev laravel-elixir-livereload`

After that in your gulpfile.js write this:

```
var elixir  = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-livereload');


elixir( function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less')
    .livereload();
});
```

Finally run

`gulp watch`

Documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-livereload

Answer (score 0):

You can use browsersync() without installing anything if you have Elixir 3.3 and Homestand

Run first: $ php artisan serve --host=0

On your gulpfile.js: mix.browserSync({proxy: 'localhost:8000'});

Answer (score 0):

You can use the laravel-elixir-browsersync-official plugin.

Your gulpfile.js should look like this:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir((mix) => {
    mix.less('app.less')
        .copy('resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap-switch/dist', 'public/packages/bootstrap-switch')
        .browserSync({
            proxy: 'your-project.url'
        })
});
```